# Copy a hash out of a hash reference

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash reference to a hash of hashes.

ref -> hash1
       hash2
       etc...

I am trying to copy 2 hashes to use to compare against each other.

```
   my %hash1 = %$ref->{ $name1}; // but I can't get it to work.  
   my %hash2 = %$ref->{ $name2};
```

I get:  Reference found where even-sized list expected at.

I know I am not declaring this right, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have error here: `%$ref->{ $name1};`, it's incorrect deference here. Please check my example below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ref = {
    hash1 => { a => 1, b => 2 },
    hash2 => { c => 3, d => 3 },
};

my $name = 'hash1';
my %hash = %{ $ref->{$name} }; # right dereference
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "implicit dereference"? I can't see any way it applies

Answer (score 3):

due to operator precedence you will need to do it this way:

```
my %hash1 = %{ $ref->{$name} };
```